# find interval of max count records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want a query to find the maximum count of records per arbitrary 24 hours on sqlserver.

For example, let I have the following table

```
event    | time
-----------------
1        | 25/1/2009 20:15:00
1        | 25/1/2009 23:15:00
5        | 10/1/2009 02:15:00
1        | 26/1/2009 00:15:00
1        | 30/1/2009 21:15:00
5        | 10/1/2009 23:15:00
```

I want a query to result

```
event | max | start time | end time
1     | 2   | 25/1/2009 20:15:00 | 26/1/2009 00:15:00
5     | 1   | 10/1/2009 02:15:00 | 11/1/2009 02:15:00
```

even of the end time was the time of the last record within the 24 hours it's okay, which means

```
event | max | start time | end time
1     | 2   | 25/1/2009 20:15:00 | 26/1/2009 20:15:00
5     | 1   | 10/1/2009 02:15:00 | 10/1/2009 23:15:00
```

How is could be done by sql-server?
I've already done this by connect the database to my java-app, but I want efficient way using pure sql-server.

Comment: And what have you tried? Where are you stuck? MySql or Sql-Server. Please, be more specific and provide proper tags.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, it's sqlserver. I have tried connect the database with my java application and do so there and it works, but I don't think it's efficient way.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: What version of SQL Server? And I really don't understand what you're trying to do, can you elaborate?

Comment: sql-server 2008 r2.
I want a query to get a 24 hours boundaries based on time column , such boundaries represent the max occurrences of an event within them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @StartDateTime datetime

;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT [event], [time]
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE [time] >= @StartDateTime
    AND [time] <= DATEADD(HOUR, 24, @StartDateTime)
)


SELECT  [event], 
        COUNT(*) As [max]
        MIN([time]) As StartTime,
        MAX([time]) As EndTime
FROM CTE
GROUP BY [event]
```

The cte gets only the relevant records from the table (where the time falls within the specified 24 hours), and the second query is just a simple group by query.

Comment: The result is got by specified time, I want to get the 24 hours boundaries that within these boundaries a specified event has most occurrence -max-.